# Button onClick() function not executed for the second time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My web page simulates a television, meaning users can switch between channels by clicking on buttons.

Channels should display videos according to the elapsed time. The initial setup is working fine i.e. if I change channel at 10th second, the next channel starts playing at 10th second and so on.

But the start button whose purpose is to reset time to zero is not working.

```html
<div id="videoSelect">
  <button data-video-url="vid1.mp4" onclick="startTime()">Start</button>
  <button data-video-url="vid2.mp4" onclick="getTime()">Channel 1</button>
  <button data-video-url="vid3.mp4" onclick="getTime()">Channel 2</button>
</div>

<video id="player" controls></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var startTime, endTime, seconds;
  //var cnt1=0, cnt2=0, cnt3=0;

  function startTime() {
    seconds = 0;
    startTime = new Date();
  }


  function getTime() {
    endTime = new Date();
    var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; //in ms
    // strip the ms
    timeDiff /= 1000;

    // get seconds 
    seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
    //document.write(seconds);
  }

  function swapVideo() {
    player.src = this.getAttribute("data-video-url");
    player.load();
    player.currentTime = seconds;
    player.play();
  }

  var videoPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button"),
    player = document.getElementById("player");

  for (var i = 0; i < videoPlayButtons.length; i++) {
    videoPlayButtons[i].addEventListener('click', swapVideo);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding your function "startTime()" with the variable "startTime" because they have the same name. Try changing The name of the function to resetTimer() or something else and it will work.

```
    var startTime, endTime, seconds;

    function startTime() {
      seconds=0;
      startTime = new Date();
    }
```